# LinqProvider that gets data from from two places and merges them

Tags: c#, linq, provider

I have a Linq query that looks something like the following

```
var query3 = from c in Session.CreateLinq<AccountTransaction>()
             join a in Session.CreateLinq<Account>() on c.Account equals a
             where c.DebitAmount >= 0
             select new { a.Name, c.DebitAmount }
;
```

The Session object interacts with a datasource behind the scenes but it also has an internal cached state which may have changes.  When I run a query I would like to query the both the internal cached state AND the datasource and then merge the results together, with the internal cached state taking precendence.

I am using re-linq for the generation of the query against the datasource which is working fine.  What I am not sure about is how to also do the query against the internal state using the same Linq query.

There's a call GetAllCached() on Session that I can use instead of Session.CreateLinq if I just wanted to query the internal state.  But I'm not sure at which point in my custom provider I can handle handing off to the datasource AND the internal state using GetAllCached().

Any suggestions appreciated from any Linq gurus.

Answer (score 2):

```
        // From Database
        var query1 = from c in Session.CreateLinq<AcccountTransaction>()
                     join a in Session.CreateLinq<Account>()
                     on c.Account equals a
                     where c.DebitAmount >= 0
                     select new { Account = a, AccountTrans = c };
                     //select new { a.Name, c.DebitAmount }; 

        // From Cache
        var query2 = from c in Session.GetAllCached<AcccountTransaction>()
                     join a in Session.GetAllCached<Account>()
                     on c.Account equals a
                     where c.DebitAmount >= 0
                     select new { Account = a, AccountTrans = c };
                     //select new { a.Name, c.DebitAmount };   



        //var query3 = query2.Union(query1.Except(query2));
        var query4 = query2.Union(query1);
```

Modified: 04:51 AM Singapore Time

Comment: `Except` is not necessary to establish precedence. `Union` will always give its first argument precedence. Also, this code will fail if any accounts have two debit transactions for the same amount.

Comment: Thanks for your highlights. I've modified accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a single custom LINQ provider for your datasource, and a (presumably type-safe) way of getting cached results as well.

In this case, I recommend just using LINQ to Objects to access your cached set. You can use `AsEnumerable` to "step out" of your custom LINQ provider into LINQ to Objects.

The `join` brings up a problem, though. Since either of these types may exist in the cache, it's not possible to push logic to the DB. For example, is it possible to have an `AccountTransaction` in the cache without its `Account` also being in the cache?

If you allow any situation in the cache (e.g., `AccountTransaction` without associated `Account` records), then you have to do the join in memory and not in the db:

```
var allDebitAccountTransactions = Session.GetAllCached<AccountTransaction>()
    .Where(x => x.DebitAmount >= 0)
    .Union(Session.CreateLinq<AccountTransaction>()
        .Where(x => x.DebitAmount >= 0));
var allAccounts = Session.GetAllCached<Account>()
    .Union(Session.CreateLinq<Account>());
var query3 = from c in allDebitAccountTransactions
             join a in allAccounts where c.Account equals a
             select new { a.Name, c.DebitAmount };
```

However, if you have more control over your cache, and only allow `AccountTransaction` objects to be present if their associated `Account` objects are present, then you can push the `join` operation to the datasource and do another one in memory, merging the results:

```
var datasourceResults = from c in Session.CreateLinq<AccountTransaction>()
    join a in Session.CreateLinq<Account>() on c.Account equals a
    where c.DebitAmount >= 0
    select new { a.Name, c.DebitAmount, c.Id };
var cacheResults = from c in Session.GetAllCached<AccountTransaction>()
    join a in Session.GetAllCached<Account>() on c.Account equals a
    where c.DebitAmount >= 0
    select new { a.Name, c.DebitAmount, c.Id };
var query3 = cacheResults.Union(datasourceResults)
    .Select(x => new { x.Name, x.DebitAmount });
```

I think. I am *not* an expert in LINQ, so I'm curious to see other responses.